# Pro-rata leave (UK) after resignation, should bank holidays be include in calculation?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, leave

I've just handed my notice in, and have a leaving date of the 7th Nov.

There's two ways to calculate my remaining leave, in my mind, including or excluding bank holidays.

**Including:**

25 days leave + 8 days bank holiday = 33 days, pro rata 311/365 = 28.12 days leave.

Total time off (including bank holidays) this year = 21 days.

So I have 8 days leave.

**OR, excluding:**

25 days leave, pro rata 311/365 = 21.3 days leave.

Total time off (excluding bank holidays) this year = 15.5 days.

So I have 6 days leave.

Honesty, 2 days isn't a big deal, but if my manager presses me to work it and get paid, it's over £200 after tax - which feels like a large enough sum to care about.

Which one should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a really strange contract, I would assume Bank Holidays are taken on the days when the UK has a National Holiday.

Since there are none of those between now and the 7th of November, I would interpret this the second way. You have six days leave remaining.

(If it helps, the two days difference would have been the 25th and 26th of December, by which time you'll already have left the company.)

Comment: Yeah, I think that makes sense. Starting the new job, I could have no leave allowance accrued but the bank holidays will still be taken on Bank holidays - so it'll all equal out in the end.

Comment: It actually **can't** be the second scenario - as the statutory holiday entitlement the OP has accrued is [23.9 days](https://www.gov.uk/calculate-your-holiday-entitlement/y/days-worked-per-week/leaving/2018-11-07/2018-01-01/5.0). The fact that his contract uses *some* of the bank holidays as part of his statutory amount complicates the math a bit though.

Comment: @motosubatsu - Good link, but if Bank Holidays are included the annual entitlement *without* bank holidays can be less than the listed statutory entitlement (eg. 20 days leave plus 8 days bank holiday would give a total that met the entitlement, but only the 20 days would count as leave that could be taken when requested).

Comment: if bank holidays are included in the total entitlement it doesn't change the required minimum and the accrual calculations for paid leave entitlement remain exactly the same (my figures are assuming the OP works full time 5 days a week but it is basically 5.6 * number of days worked in a week) whether they allow leave to be chosen by the employee or designated by the employer this doesn't change. As the OP has a higher contractual leave entitlement (33 days) this changes the multiplier (to 6.6 in the OP's case) but not the accrual method [cont]

Comment: .. hypothetically the company *could* specify a different accrual rate but only one that would be higher than the statutory minimum. With only two BH remaining in the year this would mean there would have to be some bulk leave entitlement between now and the end of the leave year, which while technically *legal* would be the weirdest holiday system I've ever seen. In fact I've literally never seen anything remotely similar and I'd imagine that HMRC would likely have issues with it.

Comment: @motosubatsu - We have a similar system at our work to the OP : Bank holidays + 23 days (taken on its own, the 23 variable days wouldn't meet the entitlement, but with bank holidays they do). Bank holidays are taken on bank holidays, giving an accrual rate based on the OP's 25 days of 25/52=0.48 days/week. 7th November is in week 45, giving accrual of 21.6 days (the OP has done it by days, but it's not far different). Subtract 15.5 already taken to give 6.1 days remaining. It's possible the employer could round to 7, or drop to 6 as week 45 isn't worked as a full week.

Comment: It's a pretty common system (I've been on the exact same split as the OP myself at more than one work place) - but it doesn't change the way the accrual works. If an employer provides paid leave on BH's then it accrues as the same rate as all other paid leave unless explicitly specified - and given the absolute omnishambles it makes of PAYE and the tax/NI implications for both the company and the employer basically everyone just accrues it evenly.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one should be used?

The answer is actually - **neither!**

**Assumptions:** your leave year starts on the 1st of January and you work 5 days a week and have been there since on or before the 1st of Jan this year.

As your *contractual* leave entitlement (33 days) exceeds the statutory minimum of 28 days then you pro-rata the amount based on the higher figure, or more specifically it's associated accrual rate.

33 days a year means you accrue 0.6346153846153846 days a week, when you leave you will have done 44.6 weeks.

44.6 * 0.6346153846153846 = 28.3 days so if you've taken 21 you have 7.3 days of leave remaining (the 0.3 makes things a little fuzzy - they may round up to 7.5 days or down to 7.0 depending upon their half-day policy)

Comment: Do you have a link (say to gov.uk) where this way of calculating is mandated?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Technically only statutory leave entitlement is mandated to be calculated this way ([link](https://www.gov.uk/calculate-your-holiday-entitlement/y/days-worked-per-week/leaving/2018-11-07/2018-01-01/5.0)), additional leave entitlement can be accrued differently but in the absence of  a clear policy or contractual clause defining how this is done HMRC would take a very dim view of any claim to it being calculated other than the standard accrual method.

Answer (score 0):

If you usually get day off on bank holidays, it should be included in the calculation
But IMHO, not pro rated, just the ones that are in your work period

For example:

25 days leave, pro rata 311/365 = 21,3 days leave.

8 days bank holiday in total
and, for the sake of calculation let say, 3 in the time you worked there this year - 24.3 days total time off

if more holidays fall on you time in the company, adjust calculation accordingly

Note:
Would be nice if down-voting people leave a comment with details of their disapproval ;)

Comment: I'm one of the down-voters, I don't want to sound harsh but, well, your answer is wrong. The rules for calculating holiday entitlement accrual are laid out pretty clearly by the government.

Answer (score -1):

Bank holidays just happen on the days they happen.

So you do the same calculation that you did with 33 days (including bank holidays) but for 25 days, and subtract the non-bank holidays you took.

If you were employed at a time with many bank holidays (say Christmas to New Years day), good for you. If you stop working on the 20th of December, bad luck, you miss out on three bank holidays.